I'm getting this error (#49101) when i'm trying to allocate Credit to a BM via API "The app must have credit partition permission"
"message": "(#49101) The app must have credit partition permission or the receiving business must be a child business manager of the extended credit owner with business management permission",
What exactly means "credit partition permission" and how i can get it to my Meta App?
Thanks in advance
I'm getting this error (#49101) when i'm trying to allocate Credit to a BM via API "message": "(#49101) The app must have credit partition permission or the receiving business must be a child business manager of the extended credit owner with business management permission".
I was expecting to be allowed to allocate credit but seems like i need this kind of permission now.
